# How to write "BiángBiáng麵" using pinyin?

Tags: pinyin, writing

Alternatively, can you write the character by strokes (that the pinyin input recognizes it and that the character can be found among all the other stored characters)?

Comment: What are you asking? I can't really get it...

Comment: Writing biangbiang with pinyin that it becomes a character.

Comment: Something I find interesting is on wiki it says "biáng" (2nd tone) but on [百度百科](http://baike.baidu.com/view/111654.htm) it says "biàng" (4th tone). And what I heard was biàng. Hmm, I don't know who is correct.

Comment: Possibly wiki isn't correct. Just guessing.

Comment: Zisea says it's biang first tone.

Answer (score 5):

**Phonetic Substitution**

Although the character cannot currently be typed into a computer, wikipedia notes that one may use a phonetic substitution. I doubt that most people would recognise this 58 stroke original character in any case but at least this may be a usable substitute.

> The Chinese character for "biáng" cannot be entered into computers.
>   Therefore phonetic substitutes like Chinese: 彪彪面; pinyin: biāobiāo
>   miàn) or Chinese: 冰冰面; pinyin: bīngbīng miàn) are often used.

(Wikipedia, n.d., [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biángbiáng_noodles#Mnemonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi%C3%A1ngbi%C3%A1ng_noodles#Mnemonics))

Answer (score 4):

Now Unicode has just supported it.
Click http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/, In detail, you can check this document https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-13.0/U130-30000.pdf.[image: The Chinese Character biáng is added]

Comment: They are on p.48. 30EDD is the Simplified Chinese version, 30EDE is the Traditional Chinese version.

Answer (score 1):

Biang biang mian 的 biang can't be typed because this character doesn't exist in any IME database.

Wikipedia:

Unicode
The character has not been added to Unicode yet, but is being considered by the IRG for inclusion in the CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E block.[1]

Comment: That's a shame. Means I would have to write it, scan it and then send it? Hmm

Comment: Wikipedia uses an image in its references you can copy if you would like. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Biáng.svg

Comment: Yeah, I would need two of those to express by writing that I would like biangbiangmian. Not ideal...But thanks.